# Wordpress pagination not working on frontpage

Tags: pagination, wordpress-theming, wordpress

Here's what i'm doing. Firstly i have a page named 'home' set as frontpage for desktop version. I'm using http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/device-theme-switcher/ to override default theme(doesn't have any front-page.php file) on mobile.

For mobile version i've created a child theme and using front-page.php to override the default desktop frontpage.

Here's the mobile version http://themes.jdsans.net/momento/ which uses the below code

```
<?php
    get_header(); 
?>

        <div id="main_container" class="container">

            <div class="row inner_wrap">

                  <div class="main-content clearfix">         

                    <div class="post-content alignleft">
                        <h4 class="column-title">
                            <span><?php _e('Recent Articles','momento_th'); ?></span>
                        </h4>

                        <ul class="clearfix single_cat_thumb">

                        <?php 
                query_posts("posts_per_page=4&paged=".$paged);
            ?>
                        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();  ?>                                                     
                            <li class="clearfix item ">

                           </li>

                           <?php endwhile; ?>                              

                        </ul>                           

                        <?php endif;  wp_reset_query(); ?>                           

                        <div class="clear"></div>                           

                    </div>  <!--post-content-->   

        </div><!-- .main-content -->  

            </div><!-- .row-->               

        </div> <!--#main_container-->
```

I've tried almost all the fixes that i've found so far but none of them works. Which includes [wordpress pagination fix](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Adding_the_.22paged.22_parameter_to_a_query) too. But i'm not getting the pagination work.

I've also read many stack's problems but so far no solution.

Also the get_query_var('paged') doesn't seems to return anything when i try add parameter paged to the query arguments

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Hi, please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997) thanks!

Comment: Removed the code link. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

before

```
query_posts("posts_per_page=4&paged=".$paged);
```

Comment: I've already tried this fix. Its listed in wordpress page i mentioned in my above post. Not worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Alright i solved it myself. If somebody else is looking for the same solution. Then in my code above in the question before the query i added

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

And in the function.php  of the child theme i added action hook pre_get_posts and hooked the function like below

```
function modify_query($query) {
    if($query->is_main_query()) {
        $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
        $query->set('paged',$paged);
    }
}
```